# Fine-grain control over Bash redirection

Tags: bash, redirect

Consider the following Bash command lines:

```
time ls         # Sends directory contents to stdout
time ls --foo   # Sends an error message to stderr (--foo is an invalid option)
```

Redirecting the outputs (normal output and error output) of `time` to one file and the outputs of `ls` to another file:

```
time ( ls       &>ls.txt ) &>time.txt
time ( ls --foo &>ls.txt ) &>time.txt
```

Redirecting error output of `time` to `time.txt` and sending the outputs of `ls` to terminal:

```
time ( ls       &>/dev/stdout ) 2>time.txt
time ( ls --foo &>/dev/stdout ) 2>time.txt
```

The above two lines combine the normal output and the error output of `ls` into stdout (fd 1). I would like to do the following: **send the outputs of `ls` to the terminal (normal output to stdout, error output to stderr), and the error output of `time` to `time.txt`**. Conceptually:

```
time ( ls       1>/dev/stdout 2>/dev/stderr ) 2>time.txt
time ( ls --foo 1>/dev/stdout 2>/dev/stderr ) 2>time.txt
```

Unfortunately, the last line isn't working properly because the error output of `ls` gets written into `time.txt`.

**How to send the normal output of `ls` to the stdout, the error output of `ls` to stderr, and the error output of `time` to `time.txt`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
{ time ls --foo 2>&3; } 3>/dev/stderr 2>time.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
time (ls --foo 2>&3) 3>/dev/stderr 2>time.txt
```

(Order of the redirects is important.)